# Keystoning in Matlab - projecting a square on the floor

Tags: matlab, math

So, as a part of an experiment I need a function that could use the projector to project something on the floor. The projector is angled so the Keystone effect comes in to play and I'd like to correct it.

I try to do that by calculating the homography matrix H. I project a square at the bottom of the projected area, measure its properties (it is shown as a trapezoid on the ground) and calculate the matrix. And then I reverse the process with the idea to use the homography matrix H (it's inverse) to calculate and project a shape on the ground that would look like the original square and not a trapezoid.

But I'm not successful. I calculate a shorter quadrangle and still get a trapeze on the ground. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the calculations but I'm not sure. I am new to Matlab :) Thx for the help. The code, with a lot of comments, is bellow.

```
function keystoning()

projArea = 100;                         % 100%
testSquare = 20;                        % test square dimension

%% Drawing a "what's supposed to be a square" on the floor 

% black background, red "sqare" dimensions 20x20, attached to the base 
% of the projection area so the base dimension of the "sqare" don't change 
% and minimal measuring is required

testX=[40 40+testSquare 40+testSquare 40];
testY=[0 0 testSquare testSquare];                 

scrsz = get(groot,'screensize');

f = figure('position',[0 0 scrsz(3) scrsz(4)],...
        'OuterPosition',[0 0 scrsz(3) scrsz(4)],...
        'toolbar','none','menubar','none','name','none',...
        'units','normalized',...
        'Color','black','Resize','Off'...
        );

figure(f);                              % focus window

fill(testX, testY,'r');

axis ([0 projArea 0 projArea])
pbaspect([1 1 1])
drawnow 

disp('*** PLACE THE NEAR PART OF THE ELEMENT AT THE END OF THE TREADMILL  ***');

%% Measuring of the shape in order to calculate the homography matrix H

disp('*** Measure the width of the base of the projection area in centimeters.  ***');
prompt = 'Enter the measured distance:  ';
projAreaM = input(prompt);

projAreaCoef=projAreaM/projArea;    % coefficient between the axes scale and the projection area

disp('*** Measure the distance between the paralel lines of the trapezoid in centimeters.  ***');
prompt = 'Enter the measured distance:  ';
trapYm = input(prompt)/projAreaCoef

disp('*** Measure the length of the longer paralel line of the trapezoid in centimeters.  ***');
prompt = 'Enter the measured length:  ';
trapXm = input(prompt)/projAreaCoef

%% Calculating the homography matrix H

% trapezoid definition

% coordinates of the first two points for the trapezoid and the square
% are the same since its at the start of the projection area

difX=(trapXm-testSquare)/2;             % length of the "pertrusions"

trapX=[testX(1) testX(2) testX(3)+difX testX(4)-difX];         
trapY=[testY(1) testY(2) trapYm trapYm];      

% variable definition

P=[testX;testY;ones(size(testX))];      % test rectangle
Q=[trapX;trapY;ones(size(trapX))];      % shown trapezoid

% homography matrix H calculation

H=Q/P;                                  % solution to the equation HP = Q

%% Testing the homography matrix H
% we want to show the rectangle on the ground

Pnew=inv(H)*P;                          
fill(Pnew(1,:),Pnew(2,:),'r');
axis ([0 projArea 0 projArea])
pbaspect([1 1 1])
drawnow
```

Comment: For a start, are you sure that the projected region is really a trapezoid and not a general quad?

Comment: I'm doing an experiment that includes me projecting something on the ground. The projector is going to be leveled straight and aimed to the ground, so with that in mind, if I project a square it should come out as a trapezoid (same as the whole projected area from the projector turns into a trapezoid with its farthest edge longer than its closer one).